# Conventions regarding the loading of resource files to a Java project

Tags: java, log4j, configuration-files, conventions

Given that I'm having issues trying to apply an external log4j configuration via `log4j.xml` I'm now interested in adopting a convention regarding the loading of resource files to Java projects.

Despite the code works displaying the message without warnings or errors, I suspect the configuration is not being really applied as changing the `ConversionPattern` makes no difference to the console output.

**Program.java**

```
package the.project.path;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

class Program {

  static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SampleLogger");
  static final File config = new File("the.project.path/conf/log4j.xml");
  static final String message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (config.exists()) {
      PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.getPath());
    } else {
      BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    try {
      logger.debug(message);
      logger.info(message);
      logger.warn(message);
      logger.error(message);
      logger.fatal(message);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
      System.out.println(exception.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="SampleConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <!--  
    TTCC is a message format used by log4j.
    TTCC is acronym for Time Thread Category Component.
    It uses the following pattern: %r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
    -->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] [%-5p] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
  <appender-ref ref="SampleConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Any advice will be really appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the DOMConfigurator, thus:

```
// Load log4j config file...
String path = "/path/to/log4j.xml");
DOMConfigurator.configure(path);

// Start Logging
LOG = Logger.getLogger(Program.class);
```

*(code ripped from my current project, so I know it works) ;-)*

As well as the above use of DOMConfigurator, you can optionally set a watch period, whereby Log4J will poll the xml file for changes, every xx millis, and then reload the changes:

```
// Load log4j config file...
String path = "/path/to/log4j.xml");
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(path, 30000); // 30sec poll

// Start Logging
LOG = Logger.getLogger(Program.class);
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately your snippet doesn't compile.

Comment: That's because it's just a snippet, not a complete method. The LOG reference is a reference to your Logger variable, and I'm sure you can remove the extra bracket left it from when I exteacted it from my own code.

Comment: The detail that solved the problem was using `.configureAndWatch()` instead of just `.configure()`, it works even with the `PropertyConfigurator`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting -Dlog4j.debug=true to see which options are being applied to log4j.
It doesn't answer your resource loading question, but it is helpful to know that usually.

Comment: Mind elaborating your suggestion a bit more? I'm using Eclipse on Linux.

Comment: If you add -Dlog4j.debug=true to your jvm args when launching your application (not Eclipse itself) Log4j will then write options that are being applied by configurator to System.out. You'll be able to see if correct configuration was loaded as soon as you start your app. These debug info lines will be prepended by "log4j:" so you won't miss them.